# SqlAlchemy Execute SQL Without Waiting For Response

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, lambda, sqlalchemy, amazon-rds

I have a python script within an AWS Lambda that is calling a stored procedure in RDS Postgres DB. The code to do so right now looks like this:

```
import os
import json
import boto3
import sqlalchemy
    
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    eng_str = 'postgresql+psycopg2://{usr_nm}:{passwd}@{rds_url}:{rds_port}/{rds_db}'.format(
        usr_nm='<usr>',
        passwd='<passwd>',
        rds_url='<host>',
        rds_port='5432',
        rds_db='postgres'
    )
    postgres_engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(eng_str, pool_size=1, max_overflow=1)

    with postgres_engine.connect() as con:
        rs = con.execute('''
            call gdh_sales_aggregator.test_stored_procedure();
        ''')
    
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Cleaning Tables Complete')
    }
```

From what I'm seeing, the lambda times out and the results of the stored procedure aren't reflected after some time passes. The stored procedure is just a group of INSERTs and DELETEs. When I check the tables after some time, the records that should have been deleted are still there, so I assume that since the lambda times out before a response from the stored procedure, the stored procedure doesn't complete.

I was wondering if there was a way to send this SQL command to execute the stored procedure to RDS without waiting for a response, so in cases where the lambda times out, the stored procedure still completes on the RDS Postgres DB.

Comment: Perhaps [the documentation](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/advanced.html#asynchronous-support) can help.